# seeking proofs: infinite series inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, inequalities, sequences-and-series

> **Question.** Numerically, the following is convincing. However, is there a proof?
>   $$\left(\sum_{k\geq1}\frac1{\sqrt{2^k+3^k}}\right)^4
> <\pi^2\left(\sum_{k\geq1}\frac1{2^k+3^k}\right)\left(\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{k^2}{2^k+3^k}\right).$$

This comes up in some recent work and the inequality seems needed.

Comment: It seems you only need 3 terms for each sum on the right and a crude upper bound for the sum on the left.

Comment: This is a research-level question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This may serve as a different approach. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $$\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{2^k+3^k}}\right)^2\leq \left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{k^2}\right)\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2}{2^k+3^k}\right),$$ which shows that $$\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{2^k+3^k}}\right)^2\leq \frac{\pi^2}6\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{k^2}{2^k+3^k}\right).$$

So it suffices to show that $$\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{2^k+3^k}}\right)^2<6\cdot \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1 {2^k+3^k}.$$

But 
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{2^k+3^k}}\right)^2 &<\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{2\cdot 6^{k/2}}}\right)^2 \\
&<6\left(\frac 1{2+3}+\sum_{k\geq 2}\frac 1{2\cdot 3^k}\right) \\
&<6\left(\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac 1{2^k+3^k}\right),
\end{align} 
where in the first inequality, the AM-GM inequality was used.

Comment: Second "<" in the penultimate line of your proof, hmm, I don't catch it:
Could you hint at how to get to factor "6" et al?

Comment: @Hanno and Cherng-tiao Perng: The second inequality in the last derivation is wrong. Both sides are geometric series the values of which violate the inequality.